# how to divide list in parts from a list by comparison on the instance inside the list

Tags: c#

suppose my `list<struct>`

in list some struct have the date 31 january

some have date 5 march

some have 12 august then

i want to make a list of all same date struct

how i can do this in c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume your struct looks like this:

```
struct YourStruct 
{
    DateTime DateProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) to get the dates:

```
List<YourStruct> list = ....;
var dates = list.GroupBy(s => s.DateProperty.Date);
```

Group by groups on unique values, so you need to group on the Date property of the DateTime instance. The code above will return an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime>>`, where the key of each group will be the corresponding date.